# R start message is included in compiling process

Tags: r, installation, compiler-errors, package, microsoft-r

I am using Microsoft R Open on CentOS 7 system, when I install `minqa` package, I found a very strange error: the R start up message is included in compiling process. How should I fix this problem?

```
r$> p_install(minqa)                                                                                                        
Installing package into ‘/home/public/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--2020-12-04 15:57:01--  http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/CRAN/src/contrib/minqa_1.2.4.tar.gz
Resolving mirrors.ustc.edu.cn (mirrors.ustc.edu.cn)... 202.38.95.110
Connecting to mirrors.ustc.edu.cn (mirrors.ustc.edu.cn)|202.38.95.110|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 53548 (52K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘/home/wsx/tmp/RtmpKkNTLF/downloaded_packages/minqa_1.2.4.tar.gz’

100%[==================================================================================>] 53,548      --.-K/s   in 0.02s   

2020-12-04 15:57:16 (2.14 MB/s) - ‘/home/wsx/tmp/RtmpKkNTLF/downloaded_packages/minqa_1.2.4.tar.gz’ saved [53548/53548]

Microsoft R Open 4.0.2
The enhanced R distribution from Microsoft
Microsoft packages Copyright (C) 2020 Microsoft Corporation

Using the Intel MKL for parallel mathematical computing (using 12 cores).

Default CRAN mirror snapshot taken on 2020-07-16.
See: https://mran.microsoft.com/.

Loading required package: pacman
* installing *source* package ‘minqa’ ...
** package ‘minqa’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c altmov.f -o altmov.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c bigden.f -o bigden.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c biglag.f -o biglag.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c bobyqa.f -o bobyqa.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c bobyqb.f -o bobyqb.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c lagmax.f -o lagmax.o
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/g++ -I/opt/microsoft/ropen/4.0.2/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I'/opt/microsoft/ropen/4.0.2/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include' -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION   -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -O2 -g  -c minqa.cpp -o minqa.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c newuoa.f -o newuoa.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c newuob.f -o newuob.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c prelim.f -o prelim.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c rescue.f -o rescue.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c trsapp.f -o trsapp.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c trsbox.f -o trsbox.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c trstep.f -o trstep.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c uobyqa.f -o uobyqa.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c uobyqb.f -o uobyqb.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c update.f -o update.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c updatebobyqa.f -o updatebobyqa.o
Loading required package: pacman
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/g++ -shared -L/opt/microsoft/ropen/4.0.2/lib64/R/lib -o minqa.so altmov.o bigden.o biglag.o bobyqa.o bobyqb.o lagmax.o minqa.o newuoa.o newuob.o prelim.o rescue.o trsapp.o trsbox.o trstep.o uobyqa.o uobyqb.o update.o updatebobyqa.o Microsoft R Open 4.0.2 The enhanced R distribution from Microsoft Microsoft packages Copyright (C) 2020 Microsoft Corporation Using the Intel MKL for parallel mathematical computing (using 12 cores). Default CRAN mirror snapshot taken on 2020-07-16. See: https://mran.microsoft.com/. -lgfortran -lm -L/opt/microsoft/ropen/4.0.2/lib64/R/lib -lR
Loading required package: pacman
g++: error: Microsoft: No such file or directory
g++: error: R: No such file or directory
g++: error: Open: No such file or directory
g++: error: 4.0.2: No such file or directory
g++: error: The: No such file or directory
g++: error: enhanced: No such file or directory
g++: error: R: No such file or directory
g++: error: distribution: No such file or directory
g++: error: from: No such file or directory
g++: error: Microsoft: No such file or directory
g++: error: Microsoft: No such file or directory
g++: error: packages: No such file or directory
g++: error: Copyright: No such file or directory
g++: error: (C): No such file or directory
g++: error: 2020: No such file or directory
g++: error: Microsoft: No such file or directory
g++: error: Corporation: No such file or directory
g++: error: Using: No such file or directory
g++: error: the: No such file or directory
g++: error: Intel: No such file or directory
g++: error: MKL: No such file or directory
g++: error: for: No such file or directory
g++: error: parallel: No such file or directory
g++: error: mathematical: No such file or directory
g++: error: computing: No such file or directory
g++: error: (using: No such file or directory
g++: error: 12: No such file or directory
g++: error: cores).: No such file or directory
g++: error: Default: No such file or directory
g++: error: CRAN: No such file or directory
g++: error: mirror: No such file or directory
g++: error: snapshot: No such file or directory
g++: error: taken: No such file or directory
g++: error: on: No such file or directory
g++: error: 2020-07-16.: No such file or directory
g++: error: See:: No such file or directory
g++: error: https://mran.microsoft.com/.: No such file or directory
make: *** [minqa.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘minqa’
* removing ‘/home/public/R/library/minqa’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/home/wsx/tmp/RtmpKkNTLF/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In utils::install.packages(package, ...) :
  installation of package ‘minqa’ had non-zero exit status
2: In p_install(minqa) :
```

Answer (score 1):

The interesting thing is that I tried to commnet all `cat()` messages in file `./lib64/R/etc/Rprofile.site` and append a `cat(" ")` make a space passed to the `gcc` and it works!

[image]